# ror How can i order by has many value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, has-many

How can I order by has-many value
I want to do something like @cases = @user.cases.order_by(step.name="shipped" desc)

I have cases table and I want if the case.step.name = "Shipped" to be at the end of the table
I have case model

```
has_many :steptations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :steps, through: :steptations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps
```

and step model

```
has_many :steptations,dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cases, through: :steptations
```

Here is my cases controller

```
def index
    @cases = @user.cases.all
end
```

Here is my case.html

```
 <% @cases.each do |item| %><tr>
        <td ><%= link_to case_path(item) do %><%= item.number %><% end %></td>
           <% if item.steptations.present? %>
          <% item.steptations.where(:status=>true).each do |t| %>
            <% if t.step&.id == 13  %>
              <td class= 'fa fa-circle red' ></td>
                <% elsif item.finished == true && t.step&.name == "Shipped"%>
                  <td class= 'fa fa-circle red' ></td>
                  <% elsif item.finished == true %>
            <td class= 'fa fa-circle dark'></td>
            <% else %>
              <td class= 'fa fa-circle green'></td> 
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <td>0</td>
        <% end %>
        
          <td> <%= link_to case_path(item) do %><%= item.pt_first_name.capitalize %> <%= item.pt_last_name.capitalize %><% end %></td>
          <td><%=link_to item.user.full_name,doctor_path(item.user)%></td>
          <td> <%= item.date_received.strftime("%b-%-d-%-y") %></td>
          <td> <%= item.due_date.strftime("%b-%-d-%-y")  %></td>
          <td><%= item.shade %></td>
          <td><%= item.mould %></td>
          <td><%= item.upper_lower %></td>
                   
          <% if item.steptations.present? %>
          <% item.steptations.where(:status=>true).each do |t| %>
            <% if t.step&.name == "Conversion"  %>
              <td class="red"><%= t.step&.name%></td>
            <% else %>
              <td><%= t.step&.name%> </td>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <td>0</td>
        <% end %>


            
          </td>
       </tr>

   <% end %></tbody>
  </table><br>
```

Comment: Making sure I understand, are you looking for a query in the `index` method where the list of cases that you are returning has all the cases with `case.step.name = "Shipped" ` at the end?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean no i want to do something like cases = user.cases.order_by(step.name="shipped" desc)

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean I am using postgress

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the SQL `ORDER BY FIELD` function. In Ruby it should be something like this:

```
Case.where(user: @user).order("FIELD(name, #{some name param variable}) desc")
```

Comment: I am getting this error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cases.step does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "cases".* FROM "cases" WHERE "cases"."step" IS NULL ...
                                             ^
: SELECT  "cases".* FROM "cases" WHERE "cases"."step" IS NULL  ORDER BY FIELD(name, shipped) desc, pt_first_name desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Case.joins(steptations: :step)
    .group("cases.id")
    .select("cases.*, 
             COUNT(steps.name) filter (where steps.name = 'shipped') as shipped")
    .order(:shipped)
```

Comment: I got this error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cases.shipped does not exist

Comment: try using order("shipped") then. What SQL query does it print out in the console ?

Comment: I got this PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "shipped" does not exist

Comment: can you tell me then what SQL query it prints out without adding ".order(:shipped)" at all?

Comment: I edited my question with adding the table

Comment: @cases=Case.order(:shipped) I got this error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cases.shipped does not exist

Comment: No, I meant the query in my answer WITHOUT the last line

Comment: Oh ok no error but still not the order i want! I want all the shipped steps to go to the bottom of the table

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to understand why you get that error since I can not replicate it. That's why I was asking for the SQL query that is being printed in the console when running the code above without the last line.

Comment: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cases.Shipped does not exist
LINE 1: ...teptations"."step_id" GROUP BY cases.id  ORDER BY "cases"."S...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  cases.*, COUNT(steps.name) filter (where steps.name = 'shipped') as shipped FROM "cases" INNER JOIN "steptations" ON "steptations"."case_id" = "cases"."id" INNER JOIN "steps" ON "steps"."id" = "steptations"."step_id" GROUP BY cases.id  ORDER BY "cases"."Shipped" ASC, pt_first_name desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Comment: So what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227233/discussion-between-daniel-sindrestean-and-nourza).